# How can I cut rows into another sheet then delete + shift for the next row without a loop freezing?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on having a production schedule sort due dates into different worksheets from a data dump sheet. I can get it working for one date manually, but I'd like it to loop for the entire range. When I try to loop it it gets stuck, I think it's because I'm deleting and shifting cells up in the groupBy sub.

```
Sub groupByDate()
'matches every date to the first cell, copies them onto a new sheet
'then deletes original range and shifts up for new top date
    Dim day As Range
    
    Dim due As Range
    Set due = Range(Range("D29"), Range("D29").End(xlDown))
    
    Dim cel As Range
    
    For Each cel In due
        'appends the range to move, if empty create range to move
        If (cel.Value = due.Cells(1).Value) Then
            If day1 Is Nothing Then
                Set day = cel.EntireRow
            Else
                Set day = Union(day, cel.EntireRow)
            End If
        End If
        
    Next
    
    day.Copy
    
    Sheets.Add.PasteSpecial
       
    day.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        
End Sub
```

Here is my loop function:

```
Sub testLoop()
'trying to loop groupBy until dump range is empty
    Dim cel As Range
    Set cel = Range("D29")
    
    Do While True
        If cel.Value <> "" Then
            groupByDate
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have one date `Range("D29").End(xlDown)` could be `D1048576`. Also the new sheet will become the active sheet and on second pass of loop after row 29 is deleted `cel` is undefined and needs to be reassigned with a next value.

```vb
Sub groupByDate()
    'matches every date to the first cell, copies them onto a new sheet
    'then deletes original range and shifts up for new top date
    Dim day As Range, ue As Range, cel As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set due = ws.Range(ws.Range("D29"), ws.Range("D29").End(xlDown))
    If due.Rows.Count > 1000000 Then Set due = ws.Range("D29") ' single date

    For Each cel In due
        'appends the range to move, if empty create range to move
        If (cel.Value = due.Cells(1).Value) Then
            If day Is Nothing Then
                Set day = cel.EntireRow
            Else
                Set day = Union(day, cel.EntireRow)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    
    day.Copy
    Sheets.Add.PasteSpecial
    day.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ws.Activate ' return to active sheet
        
End Sub

Sub testLoop()
    'trying to loop groupBy until dump range is empty
    Dim cel As Range
    Set cel = Range("D29")
    
    Do While cel.Value <> ""
        groupByDate0
        Set cel = Range("D29")
    Loop
    
End Sub
```